# Java 8 : Comma separated string to Generic List using Stream.of()

Tags: java, java-8

I need a common static function for convert comma separated string to a generic list.

```
String str = "1,2,4,5";
List<BigInteger> lists = Stream.of(str.split(",")).map(String::trim).map(BigInteger::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Instead of this `.map(BigInteger::new)` I need a generic expression to convert to generic list

Comment: Sounds like you need a `Function<String, T>` to convert a string to your generic type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BigInteger::new` step executes a `Function<String, BigInteger>` to convert each string to an instance of `BigInteger`. If you want to do this for a generic type, you need a function to convert a string to an instance of your generic type. That means you need a `Function<String, T>`.

Given `Function<String, T> converter`, you can do:

```
List<T> items = Stream.of(str.split(","))
                      .map(String::trim)
                      .map(converter)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```